# How is the question?sort=frequent/faq search sorted? How can I find frequent questions?

Tags: support, search

I see this on [UL search](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent):

[image]

I would like to know how is this sorted actually as the amount of "views" apparently doesn't mean that it's frequent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are organized by amount of linked questions. The first and second questions in your screenshot has exactly 39 linked questions, the third has 37.

Apparently it doesn't count duplicates questions (which would be a killer feature) so, some questions that were commented or referenced plays in the sorting.

Comment: How do you know they have those many links?

Comment: @slm in the sidebar, there's "Linked" section, there's a link at the end that reads "see more linked questions…". That presents you with `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/postid` which ultimately counts the linked questions.